# How to get email address from a string

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am searching for a way to retrieve all emails addresses from a given string.
For example: if i have the string "AB CD [ABCD@gmail.com]" i want to receive only "ABCD@gmail.com".

I guess i should use RegExp and String match function, but i am not sure how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.match` is indeed the way to go:

```
var email:String = "foo foo bar@barbar.com sploof";
var matches:Array = email.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/g);
```

This uses a regex to match a RFC2822 from the community regexes of [regexr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) about a proper regexp to match emails. And yes, you should use the `match` function of your language but keep in mind that you have to adapt your regex to your email pattern, like, in this case, you may include the presence of `[` and `]`.

I also advice to use [Regex Buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) to try and test regexp, it's the best tool out there imho.